# Ubuntu server not installing

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server on my laptop.   I have cleared off windows 10.    I have the iso file on a USB and I am booting from it.    It starts to install but I get a message No boot filename received. The error message is PXE-E53  Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

USB will not boot ISO from it. You need to make bootable usb. 
If you already use ubuntu, You can check out [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu). Visit [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to make bootable usb from Windows machine.

Comment: I have made a bootable usb from another windows machince.  How do I know get Ubuntu to install?  I am at a c prompt.

Comment: I should add that I do not have a CD drive.   I installed the ISO on the bootable usb will that work?

Comment: No, that will not work. You need to make bootable USB. After making successfully bootable USB, you will be boot Ubuntu same as CD/DVD drive.